# Error in inserting a row to an mysql database table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I try to insert a row to my DB table as follows:

```
$selected = mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name);
if(!$selected){
    $mail_Subject = 'Error in selecting DB: ' . mysqli_error($link);        
    mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
    mysqli_close($link);
    exit;
}

// Add the line to the database!
if(!mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tokens (user_id, user_name, transaction_id, token_type, token_meta, date) VALUES ('-3', 'nisui2', 'blabla2', '111', '111 meta', '');")){
    $mail_Subject = 'Error in insertion: ' . mysqli_error($link);       
    mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
    mysqli_close($link);
    exit;
}
```

From some reason I get an email with the subject "Error in insertion:", with no error details.

Can you spot what am I doing wrong?

Also, can you tell me a way to debug this? (how can I know what the problem was?)

Comment: You're using mysqli - but there's only one argument !?!? And you're mixing mysql_ and mysqli - that's not going to work

Comment: I changed it according to what you said. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you enter that query directly into the mysql console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$link` as first parameter to your call:

### [mysqli_query($link, $query [, $resultmode])](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT …");
```

Answer (score 2):

You'r selecting the Database with  "mysql_select_db" but you'r querying with msqli

try

```
   $selected = mysqli_select_db($db_name, $link);
```

Comment: I changed it, but still I get the Error in insertion. Do you know how can I know what is the concrete error?

Comment: try "mysqli_error($link)", 

did you made the database connection with $link = mysqli_connect ?

Comment: yes, $link is the connection to db. I did change it, still doesn't work... (and doesn't give error info)